# How to iterate day in php?

Tags: php

I need to get the next 7 (or more) dates except sunday. Firstly i did it like

```
$end_date = new DateTime();
$end_date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));

$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime(),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    $end_date
);
```

And after checked `$period` in `foreach`. But then i noticed that if i remove Sunday i need to add one more day to the end and this is each time when Sunday is...  Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sunday isn't always in your list of 7 days?Don't you have to add one more day every time?

Comment: @Dchris new date starts from now and can be 7 days or more(for example 14 days), so i need to remove each sunday from this period and add one extra day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$start = new DateTime('');
$end = new DateTime('+7 days');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if ($dt->format("N") === 7) {
        $end->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    else  {
        echo $dt->format("l Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/KocKp)

Comment: as i said, if `$dt` is sunday i need to add extra day in $period;

Comment: If I knew how to add, I would not ask this question.

Comment: for example if i need 2 days, i set end like `$end->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));` and as a result i should get 18 - Saturday, 
20 - Monday, but i get 18 - Saturday, 21 - Tuesday

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of using iterators, to keep the actual loop as simple as possible.

```
$days_wanted = 7;

$base_period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime(),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    ceil($days_wanted * (8 / 7)) // Enough recurrences to exclude Sundays
);

// PHP >= 5.4.0 (lower versions can have their own FilterIterator here)
$no_sundays = new CallbackFilterIterator(
    new IteratorIterator($base_period),
    function ($date) {
        return $date->format('D') !== 'Sun';
    }
);

$period_without_sundays = new LimitIterator($no_sundays, 0, $days_wanted);

foreach ($period_without_sundays as $day) {
    echo $day->format('D Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UNIX time, adding day and if day is Sunday, add another one.
First day of your list will be eg. today at 12:00. Than you add 24 * 60 * 60 to get next day, and so on. Convert UNIX to day is simple, use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$actDay = time();
$daysCount = 0;
while(true)
{
   if (date("D", $actDay) != "Sun") 
   {
     //do something with day
     $daysCount++;
   }

   if ($daysCount >= LIMIT) break;

   $actDay += 24 * 60 * 60;
}
```

Comment: Please - when somebody has moved beyond the basics to using DateTime, DateInterval and DatePeriod, DON'T suggest they revert to using the unix timestamp based date functions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove days from a `DatePeriod`, but you can simply keep a count of non-Sundays and keep iterating until you have accumulated 7 of them:

```
$date = new DateTime();

for ($days = 0; $days < 7; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
    if ($date->format('w') == 0) {
        // it's a Sunday, skip it
        continue;
    }

    ++$days;
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
}
```